# Is there any way to view current index state in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

I want to investigate data which is actually stored as cosmos db index.
I have defined custom indexing policy and now, according to metrics in azure portal, my actual data size is much smaller than my index data size (270Mb vs 130Mb).

So, is there any API or some other way, so I can view what is data is stored in index (like we can view cosmos db documents)?

Did somebody faced with situation where index size is greater than data size?? 
(it seems weird for me coz index is build upon data, so it should be smaller than data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched Azure Cosmos DB [Restful API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) and no such api for retrieving the data stored in the index.

Per my knowledge, have index size > data size is rare, but not "bad" or "wrong".It could happen. You need to make sure your index policy is useful for your database operation performance.

If you concern the cost of your cosmos db account, you could check the [price](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) doc.It's affected by `RUs` mainly.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! the main reason why I started investigating this question is that after deleting documents in azure my data size decreased significantly, but index size remain the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwnvF.png

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk I checked the cosmos db index document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies and no any statement about  index drop with data drop. I also search the mongodb doc because it's similar to cosmos db. Index could be dropped with the collection deleted, not related to data change.